# scale SVGs inside div

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a number of SVGs which I position relative to one another using css and I'd like to scale ALL of them proportionally to the size of a parent/container div. (For instance it should "fit" inside the red div while preserving the aspect ratio)

I've tried using `preserveAspectRatio` but I'm out of ideas because I am so new to working with SVGs. Any help appreciated!

```css
.human-body {
position: relative;
height: 260px;
width: 200px;
background-color: red;
}

.human-body svg:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}

.human-body svg:hover path {
fill: #FDE725FF;
}

.human-body svg {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
}

.human-body svg#head {
margin-left: -28.5px;
top: -6px;
}

.human-body svg#left-shoulder {
margin-left: -53.5px;
top: 69px;
}

.human-body svg#right-shoulder {
margin-left: 13.5px;
top: 69px;
}

.human-body svg#left-arm {
margin-left: -78px;
top: 112px;
}

.human-body svg#right-arm {
margin-left: 38px;
top: 112px;
}

.human-body svg#chest {
margin-left: -43.5px;
top: 88px;
}

.human-body svg#stomach {
margin-left: -37.5px;
top: 130px;
}

.human-body svg#left-leg {
margin-left: -46.5px;
top: 205px;
z-index: 9999;
}

.human-body svg#right-leg {
margin-left: 1.5px;
top: 205px;
z-index: 9999;
}

.human-body svg#left-hand {
margin-left: -102.5px;
top: 224px;
}

.human-body svg#right-hand {
margin-left: 66.5px;
top: 224px;
}

.human-body svg#left-foot {
margin-left: -35.5px;
top: 455px;
}

.human-body svg#right-foot {
margin-left: 5.5px;
top: 455px;
}

#area {
display: block;
width: 100%;
clear: both;
padding: 10px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 25px;
font-family: Courier New;
color: #a5a5a5;
}

#area #data {
color: black;
}

.well{min-height:700px;}
```

```html
<div class="human-body">
<svg preserveAspectRatio='none' overflow='auto' class='part head' fill='{data[1]}' data-position='head' id='head' class='head' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='56.594' height='95.031' viewBox='0 0 56.594 95.031'>
            <path data-anatomy='head' class='head' d='M15.92 68.5l8.8 12.546 3.97 13.984-9.254-7.38-4.622-15.848zm27.1 0l-8.8 12.546-3.976 13.988 9.254-7.38 4.622-15.848zm6.11-27.775l.108-11.775-21.16-14.742L8.123 26.133 8.09 40.19l-3.24.215 1.462 9.732 5.208 1.81 2.36 11.63 9.72 11.018 10.856-.324 9.56-10.37 1.918-11.952 5.207-1.81 1.342-9.517zm-43.085-1.84l-.257-13.82L28.226 11.9l23.618 15.755-.216 10.37 4.976-17.085L42.556 2.376 25.49 0 10.803 3.673.002 24.415z'/>
            </svg>
            <svg preserveAspectRatio='none' overflow='auto' class='part' fill='{data[2]}' data-position='left-shoulder' id='left-shoulder' class='left-shoulder' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='109.532' height='46.594' viewBox='0 0 109.532 46.594'>
            <path data-anatomy='left-shoulder' d='m 38.244,-0.004 1.98,9.232 -11.653,2.857 -7.474,-2.637 z M 17.005,10.536 12.962,8.35 0.306,22.35 0.244,27.675 c 0,0 16.52,-17.015 16.764,-17.14 z m 1.285,0.58 C 18.3,11.396 0.528,30.038 0.528,30.038 L -0.01,46.595 6.147,36.045 18.017,30.989 26.374,15.6 Z'/>
            </svg>
            <svg preserveAspectRatio='none' overflow='auto' class='part' fill='{data[3]}' data-position='right-shoulder' id='right-shoulder' class='right-shoulder' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='109.532' height='46.594' viewBox='0 0 109.532 46.594'>
            <path data-anatomy='right-shoulder' d='m 3.2759972,-0.004 -1.98,9.232 11.6529998,2.857 7.473999,-2.637 z m 21.2379988,10.54 4.044,-2.187 12.656,14 0.07,5.33 c 0,0 -16.524,-17.019 -16.769,-17.144 z m -1.285,0.58 c -0.008,0.28 17.762,18.922 17.762,18.922 l 0.537,16.557 -6.157,-10.55 -11.871,-5.057 L 15.147997,15.6 Z'/>
            </svg>
            <svg preserveAspectRatio='none' overflow='auto' class='part' fill='{data[4]}' data-position='left-arm' id='left-arm' class='left-arm' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='156.344' height='119.25' viewBox='0 0 156.344 119.25'>
            <path data-anatomy='left-arm' d='m21.12,56.5a1.678,1.678 0 0 1 -0.427,0.33l0.935,8.224l12.977,-13.89l1.2,-8.958a168.2,168.2 0 0 0 -14.685,14.294zm1.387,12.522l-18.07,48.91l5.757,1.333l19.125,-39.44l3.518,-22.047l-10.33,11.244zm-5.278,-18.96l2.638,18.74l-17.2,46.023l-2.657,-1.775l6.644,-35.518l10.575,-27.47zm18.805,-12.323a1.78,1.78 0 0 1 0.407,-0.24l3.666,-27.345l-7.037,-10.139l-7.258,10.58l-6.16,37.04l0.566,4.973a151.447,151.447 0 0 1 15.808,-14.87l0.008,0.001zm-13.742,-28.906l-3.3,35.276l-2.2,-26.238l5.5,-9.038z'/>
            </svg>
            <svg preserveAspectRatio='none' overflow='auto' class='part'fill='{data[5]}' data-position='right-arm' id='right-arm' class='right-arm' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='156.344' height='119.25' viewBox='0 0 156.344 119.25'>
            <path data-anatomy='right-arm' d='m 18.997,56.5 a 1.678,1.678 0 0 0 0.427,0.33 L 18.489,65.054 5.512,51.164 4.312,42.206 A 168.2,168.2 0 0 1 18.997,56.5 Z m -1.387,12.522 18.07,48.91 -5.757,1.333 L 10.798,79.825 7.28,57.778 17.61,69.022 Z m 5.278,-18.96 -2.638,18.74 17.2,46.023 2.657,-1.775 L 33.463,77.532 22.888,50.062 Z M 4.083,37.739 A 1.78,1.78 0 0 0 3.676,37.499 L 0.01,10.154 7.047,0.015 l 7.258,10.58 6.16,37.04 -0.566,4.973 A 151.447,151.447 0 0 0 4.091,37.738 l -0.008,10e-4 z m 13.742,-28.906 3.3,35.276 2.2,-26.238 -5.5,-9.038 z'/>
            </svg>
            <svg preserveAspectRatio='none' overflow='auto' class='part' fill='{data[6]}' data-position='chest' id='chest' class='chest' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='86.594' height='45.063' viewBox='0 0 86.594 45.063'>
            <path data-anatomy='chest' d='M19.32 0l-9.225 16.488-10.1 5.056 6.15 4.836 4.832 14.07 11.2 4.616 17.85-8.828-4.452-34.7zm47.934 0l9.225 16.488 10.1 5.056-6.15 4.836-4.833 14.07-11.2 4.616-17.844-8.828 4.45-34.7z'/>
            </svg>
            <svg preserveAspectRatio='none' overflow='auto' class='part' fill='{data[7]}' data-position='stomach' id='stomach' class='stomach' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='75.25' height='107.594' viewBox='0 0 75.25 107.594'>
            <path data-anatomy='stomach' d='M19.25 7.49l16.6-7.5-.5 12.16-14.943 7.662zm-10.322 8.9l6.9 3.848-.8-9.116zm5.617-8.732L1.32 2.15 6.3 15.6zm-8.17 9.267l9.015 5.514 1.54 11.028-8.795-5.735zm15.53 5.89l.332 8.662 12.286-2.665.664-11.826zm14.61 84.783L33.28 76.062l-.08-20.53-11.654-5.736-1.32 37.5zM22.735 35.64L22.57 46.3l11.787 3.166.166-16.657zm-14.16-5.255L16.49 35.9l1.1 11.25-8.8-7.06zm8.79 22.74l-9.673-7.28-.84 9.78L-.006 68.29l10.564 14.594 5.5.883 1.98-20.735zM56 7.488l-16.6-7.5.5 12.16 14.942 7.66zm10.32 8.9l-6.9 3.847.8-9.116zm-5.617-8.733L73.93 2.148l-4.98 13.447zm8.17 9.267l-9.015 5.514-1.54 11.03 8.8-5.736zm-15.53 5.89l-.332 8.662-12.285-2.665-.664-11.827zm-14.61 84.783l3.234-31.536.082-20.532 11.65-5.735 1.32 37.5zm13.78-71.957l.166 10.66-11.786 3.168-.166-16.657zm14.16-5.256l-7.915 5.514-1.1 11.25 8.794-7.06zm-8.79 22.743l9.673-7.28.84 9.78 6.862 12.66-10.564 14.597-5.5.883-1.975-20.74z'/>
            </svg>
            <svg preserveAspectRatio='none' overflow='auto' class='part' fill='{data[8]}' data-position='left-leg' id='left-leg' class='left-leg' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='93.626' height='250.625' viewBox='0 0 93.626 250.625'>
            <path data-anatomy='left-leg' d='m 18.00179,139.99461 -0.664,5.99 4.647,5.77 1.55,9.1 3.1,1.33 2.655,-13.755 1.77,-4.88 -1.55,-3.107 z m 20.582,0.444 -3.32,9.318 -7.082,13.755 1.77,12.647 5.09,-14.2 4.205,-7.982 z m -26.557,-12.645 5.09,27.29 -3.32,-1.777 -2.656,8.875 z m 22.795,42.374 -1.55,4.88 -3.32,20.634 -0.442,27.51 4.65,26.847 -0.223,-34.39 4.87,-13.754 0.663,-15.087 z m -10.623,12.424 1.106,41.267 c 14.157565,64.57987 -5.846437,10.46082 -16.8199998,-29.07 l 5.5329998,-36.384 z m -9.71,-178.164003 0,22.476 15.71,31.073 9.923,30.850003 -1.033,-21.375 z m 25.49,30.248 0.118,-0.148 -0.793,-2.024 -16.545,-18.16 -1.242,-0.44 10.984,28.378 z m -6.255,10.766 6.812,17.6 2.274,-21.596 -1.344,-3.43 z m -26.4699998,17.82 0.827,25.340003 12.8159998,35.257 -3.928,10.136 -12.6099998,-44.51 z M 31.81879,76.04161 l 0.345,0.826 6.47,15.48 -4.177,38.342 -6.594,-3.526 5.715,-35.7 z m -21.465,-74.697003 0.827,21.373 L 4.1527902,65.02561 0.84679017,30.870607 Z m 2.068,27.323 14.677,32.391 3.307,26.000003 -6.2,36.58 -13.437,-37.241 -0.8269998,-38.342003 z'/>
            </svg>
            <svg preserveAspectRatio='none' overflow='auto' class='part' fill='{data[9]}' data-position='right-leg' id='right-leg' class='right-leg' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='80' height='250.625' viewBox='0 0 80 250.625'>
            <path data-anatomy='right-leg' d='m 26.664979,139.7913 0.663,5.99 -4.647,5.77 -1.55,9.1 -3.1,1.33 -2.655,-13.755 -1.77,-4.88 1.55,-3.107 z m -20.5820002,0.444 3.3200005,9.318 7.0799997,13.755 -1.77,12.647 -5.0899997,-14.2 -4.2000005,-7.987 z m 3.7620005,29.73 1.5499997,4.88 3.32,20.633 0.442,27.51 -4.648,26.847 0.22,-34.39 -4.8670002,-13.754 -0.67,-15.087 z m 10.6229997,12.424 -1.107,41.267 -8.852,33.28 9.627,-4.55 16.046,-57.8 -5.533,-36.384 z m -13.9460002,74.991 c -5.157661,19.45233 -2.5788305,9.72616 0,0 z M 30.177979,4.225305 l 0,22.476 -15.713,31.072 -9.9230002,30.850005 1.033,-21.375005 z m -25.4930002,30.249 -0.118,-0.15 0.793,-2.023 16.5450002,-18.16 1.24,-0.44 -10.98,28.377 z m 6.2550002,10.764 -6.8120002,17.6 -2.274,-21.595 1.344,-3.43 z m 26.47,17.82 -0.827,25.342005 -12.816,35.25599 3.927,10.136 12.61,-44.50999 z m -24.565,12.783005 -0.346,0.825 -6.4700002,15.48 4.1780002,38.34199 6.594,-3.527 -5.715,-35.69999 z m 19.792,51.74999 -5.09,27.29 3.32,-1.776 2.655,8.875 z m 1.671,-126.452995 -0.826,21.375 7.03,42.308 3.306,-34.155 z m -2.066,27.325 -14.677,32.392 -3.308,26.000005 6.2,36.57999 13.436,-37.23999 0.827,-38.340005 z'/>
            </svg>
            <svg preserveAspectRatio='none' overflow='auto' class='part' fill='{data[10]}' data-position='left-hand' id='left-hand' class='left-hand' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='90' height='38.938' viewBox='0 0 90 38.938'>
            <path data-anatomy='left-hand' d='m 21.255,-0.00198191 2.88,6.90000201 8.412,1.335 0.664,12.4579799 -4.427,17.8 -2.878,-0.22 2.8,-11.847 -2.99,-0.084 -4.676,12.6 -3.544,-0.446 4.4,-12.736 -3.072,-0.584 -5.978,13.543 -4.428,-0.445 6.088,-14.1 -2.1,-1.25 L 4.878,34.934 1.114,34.489 12.4,12.9 11.293,11.12 0.665,15.57 0,13.124 8.635,5.3380201 Z' />
            </svg>
            <svg preserveAspectRatio='none' overflow='auto' class='part' fill='{data[11]}' data-position='right-hand' id='right-hand' class='right-hand' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='90' height='38.938' viewBox='0 0 90 38.938'>
            <path data-anatomy='right-hand' d='m 13.793386,-0.00198533 -2.88,6.90000163 -8.4120002,1.335 -0.664,12.4579837 4.427,17.8 2.878,-0.22 -2.8,-11.847 2.99,-0.084 4.6760002,12.6 3.544,-0.446 -4.4,-12.736 3.072,-0.584 5.978,13.543 4.428,-0.445 -6.088,-14.1 2.1,-1.25 7.528,12.012 3.764,-0.445 -11.286,-21.589 1.107,-1.78 10.628,4.45 0.665,-2.447 -8.635,-7.7859837 z'/>
            </svg>
            <svg preserveAspectRatio='none' overflow='auto' class='part' fill='{data[12]}'  data-position='left-foot' id='left-foot' class='left-foot' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='30' height='30' viewBox='0 0 30 30'>
            <path data-anatomy='left-foot' d='m 19.558357,1.92821 c -22.1993328,20.55867 -11.0996668,10.27933 0,0 z m 5.975,5.989 -0.664,18.415 -1.55,6.435 -4.647,0 -1.327,-4.437 -1.55,-0.222 0.332,4.437 -5.864,-1.778 -1.5499998,-0.887 -6.64,-1.442 -0.22,-5.214 6.418,-10.87 4.4259998,-5.548 c 9.991542,-3.26362 9.41586,-8.41457 12.836,1.111 z'/>
            </svg>
            <svg preserveAspectRatio='none' overflow='auto' class='part' fill='{data[13]}' data-position='right-foot' id='right-foot' class='right-foot' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='90' height='38.938' viewBox='0 0 90 38.938'>
            <path data-anatomy='right-foot' d='m 11.723492,2.35897 c -40.202667,20.558 -20.1013335,10.279 0,0 z m -5.9740005,5.989 0.663,18.415 1.546,6.435 4.6480005,0 1.328,-4.437 1.55,-0.222 -0.333,4.437 5.863,-1.778 1.55,-0.887 6.638,-1.442 0.222,-5.214 -6.418,-10.868 -4.426,-5.547 -10.8440005,-4.437 z'/>
            </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: You should have just made all this 1 svg and used a group for each body part.

Comment: Please pardon my ignorance @SeanStopnik , what would this look like? remove all the svgs and just group the paths inside a <g></g>?

Comment: Yes, since that is what you are trying to do anyway. Having each item a separate svg doesn't make much sense. This is all one svg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I couldn't change it according to SVG I managed to put it within a box but scaling up and repositioning it.
Hope it helped.

```css
.human-body {
position: relative;
height: 500px;
width: 230px;

background-color: red;
}

.human-body svg:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}

.human-body svg:hover path {
fill: #FDE725FF;
}

.human-body svg {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
}

.human-body svg#head {
margin-left: -28.5px;
top: 3px;
}

.human-body svg#left-shoulder {
margin-left: -53.5px;
top: 73px;
}

.human-body svg#right-shoulder {
margin-left: 13.5px;
top: 73px;
}

.human-body svg#left-arm {
margin-left: -78px;
top: 115px;
}

.human-body svg#right-arm {
margin-left: 38px;
top: 115px;
}

.human-body svg#chest {
margin-left: -43.5px;
top: 93px;
}

.human-body svg#stomach {
margin-left: -37.5px;
top: 133px;
}

.human-body svg#left-leg {
margin-left: -46.5px;
top: 207px;
z-index: 9999;
}

.human-body svg#right-leg {
margin-left: 1.5px;
top: 207px;
z-index: 9999;
}

.human-body svg#left-hand {
margin-left: -102.5px;
top: 226px;
}

.human-body svg#right-hand {
margin-left: 66.5px;
top: 226px;
}

.human-body svg#left-foot {
margin-left: -35.5px;
top: 457px;
}

.human-body svg#right-foot {
margin-left: 5.5px;
top: 457px;
}

#area {
display: block;
width: 100%;
clear: both;
padding: 10px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 25px;
font-family: Courier New;
color: #a5a5a5;
}

#area #data {
color: black;
}

.well{min-height:700px;}
```

```html
<div class="human-body">
<svg preserveAspectRatio='none' overflow='auto' class='part head' fill='{data[1]}' data-position='head' id='head' class='head' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='56.594' height='95.031' viewBox='0 0 56.594 95.031'>
            <path data-anatomy='head' class='head' d='M15.92 68.5l8.8 12.546 3.97 13.984-9.254-7.38-4.622-15.848zm27.1 0l-8.8 12.546-3.976 13.988 9.254-7.38 4.622-15.848zm6.11-27.775l.108-11.775-21.16-14.742L8.123 26.133 8.09 40.19l-3.24.215 1.462 9.732 5.208 1.81 2.36 11.63 9.72 11.018 10.856-.324 9.56-10.37 1.918-11.952 5.207-1.81 1.342-9.517zm-43.085-1.84l-.257-13.82L28.226 11.9l23.618 15.755-.216 10.37 4.976-17.085L42.556 2.376 25.49 0 10.803 3.673.002 24.415z'/>
            </svg>
            <svg preserveAspectRatio='none' overflow='auto' class='part' fill='{data[2]}' data-position='left-shoulder' id='left-shoulder' class='left-shoulder' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='109.532' height='46.594' viewBox='0 0 109.532 46.594'>
            <path data-anatomy='left-shoulder' d='m 38.244,-0.004 1.98,9.232 -11.653,2.857 -7.474,-2.637 z M 17.005,10.536 12.962,8.35 0.306,22.35 0.244,27.675 c 0,0 16.52,-17.015 16.764,-17.14 z m 1.285,0.58 C 18.3,11.396 0.528,30.038 0.528,30.038 L -0.01,46.595 6.147,36.045 18.017,30.989 26.374,15.6 Z'/>
            </svg>
            <svg preserveAspectRatio='none' overflow='auto' class='part' fill='{data[3]}' data-position='right-shoulder' id='right-shoulder' class='right-shoulder' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='109.532' height='46.594' viewBox='0 0 109.532 46.594'>
            <path data-anatomy='right-shoulder' d='m 3.2759972,-0.004 -1.98,9.232 11.6529998,2.857 7.473999,-2.637 z m 21.2379988,10.54 4.044,-2.187 12.656,14 0.07,5.33 c 0,0 -16.524,-17.019 -16.769,-17.144 z m -1.285,0.58 c -0.008,0.28 17.762,18.922 17.762,18.922 l 0.537,16.557 -6.157,-10.55 -11.871,-5.057 L 15.147997,15.6 Z'/>
            </svg>
            <svg preserveAspectRatio='none' overflow='auto' class='part' fill='{data[4]}' data-position='left-arm' id='left-arm' class='left-arm' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='156.344' height='119.25' viewBox='0 0 156.344 119.25'>
            <path data-anatomy='left-arm' d='m21.12,56.5a1.678,1.678 0 0 1 -0.427,0.33l0.935,8.224l12.977,-13.89l1.2,-8.958a168.2,168.2 0 0 0 -14.685,14.294zm1.387,12.522l-18.07,48.91l5.757,1.333l19.125,-39.44l3.518,-22.047l-10.33,11.244zm-5.278,-18.96l2.638,18.74l-17.2,46.023l-2.657,-1.775l6.644,-35.518l10.575,-27.47zm18.805,-12.323a1.78,1.78 0 0 1 0.407,-0.24l3.666,-27.345l-7.037,-10.139l-7.258,10.58l-6.16,37.04l0.566,4.973a151.447,151.447 0 0 1 15.808,-14.87l0.008,0.001zm-13.742,-28.906l-3.3,35.276l-2.2,-26.238l5.5,-9.038z'/>
            </svg>
            <svg preserveAspectRatio='none' overflow='auto' class='part'fill='{data[5]}' data-position='right-arm' id='right-arm' class='right-arm' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='156.344' height='119.25' viewBox='0 0 156.344 119.25'>
            <path data-anatomy='right-arm' d='m 18.997,56.5 a 1.678,1.678 0 0 0 0.427,0.33 L 18.489,65.054 5.512,51.164 4.312,42.206 A 168.2,168.2 0 0 1 18.997,56.5 Z m -1.387,12.522 18.07,48.91 -5.757,1.333 L 10.798,79.825 7.28,57.778 17.61,69.022 Z m 5.278,-18.96 -2.638,18.74 17.2,46.023 2.657,-1.775 L 33.463,77.532 22.888,50.062 Z M 4.083,37.739 A 1.78,1.78 0 0 0 3.676,37.499 L 0.01,10.154 7.047,0.015 l 7.258,10.58 6.16,37.04 -0.566,4.973 A 151.447,151.447 0 0 0 4.091,37.738 l -0.008,10e-4 z m 13.742,-28.906 3.3,35.276 2.2,-26.238 -5.5,-9.038 z'/>
            </svg>
            <svg preserveAspectRatio='none' overflow='auto' class='part' fill='{data[6]}' data-position='chest' id='chest' class='chest' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='86.594' height='45.063' viewBox='0 0 86.594 45.063'>
            <path data-anatomy='chest' d='M19.32 0l-9.225 16.488-10.1 5.056 6.15 4.836 4.832 14.07 11.2 4.616 17.85-8.828-4.452-34.7zm47.934 0l9.225 16.488 10.1 5.056-6.15 4.836-4.833 14.07-11.2 4.616-17.844-8.828 4.45-34.7z'/>
            </svg>
            <svg preserveAspectRatio='none' overflow='auto' class='part' fill='{data[7]}' data-position='stomach' id='stomach' class='stomach' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='75.25' height='107.594' viewBox='0 0 75.25 107.594'>
            <path data-anatomy='stomach' d='M19.25 7.49l16.6-7.5-.5 12.16-14.943 7.662zm-10.322 8.9l6.9 3.848-.8-9.116zm5.617-8.732L1.32 2.15 6.3 15.6zm-8.17 9.267l9.015 5.514 1.54 11.028-8.795-5.735zm15.53 5.89l.332 8.662 12.286-2.665.664-11.826zm14.61 84.783L33.28 76.062l-.08-20.53-11.654-5.736-1.32 37.5zM22.735 35.64L22.57 46.3l11.787 3.166.166-16.657zm-14.16-5.255L16.49 35.9l1.1 11.25-8.8-7.06zm8.79 22.74l-9.673-7.28-.84 9.78L-.006 68.29l10.564 14.594 5.5.883 1.98-20.735zM56 7.488l-16.6-7.5.5 12.16 14.942 7.66zm10.32 8.9l-6.9 3.847.8-9.116zm-5.617-8.733L73.93 2.148l-4.98 13.447zm8.17 9.267l-9.015 5.514-1.54 11.03 8.8-5.736zm-15.53 5.89l-.332 8.662-12.285-2.665-.664-11.827zm-14.61 84.783l3.234-31.536.082-20.532 11.65-5.735 1.32 37.5zm13.78-71.957l.166 10.66-11.786 3.168-.166-16.657zm14.16-5.256l-7.915 5.514-1.1 11.25 8.794-7.06zm-8.79 22.743l9.673-7.28.84 9.78 6.862 12.66-10.564 14.597-5.5.883-1.975-20.74z'/>
            </svg>
            <svg preserveAspectRatio='none' overflow='auto' class='part' fill='{data[8]}' data-position='left-leg' id='left-leg' class='left-leg' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='93.626' height='250.625' viewBox='0 0 93.626 250.625'>
            <path data-anatomy='left-leg' d='m 18.00179,139.99461 -0.664,5.99 4.647,5.77 1.55,9.1 3.1,1.33 2.655,-13.755 1.77,-4.88 -1.55,-3.107 z m 20.582,0.444 -3.32,9.318 -7.082,13.755 1.77,12.647 5.09,-14.2 4.205,-7.982 z m -26.557,-12.645 5.09,27.29 -3.32,-1.777 -2.656,8.875 z m 22.795,42.374 -1.55,4.88 -3.32,20.634 -0.442,27.51 4.65,26.847 -0.223,-34.39 4.87,-13.754 0.663,-15.087 z m -10.623,12.424 1.106,41.267 c 14.157565,64.57987 -5.846437,10.46082 -16.8199998,-29.07 l 5.5329998,-36.384 z m -9.71,-178.164003 0,22.476 15.71,31.073 9.923,30.850003 -1.033,-21.375 z m 25.49,30.248 0.118,-0.148 -0.793,-2.024 -16.545,-18.16 -1.242,-0.44 10.984,28.378 z m -6.255,10.766 6.812,17.6 2.274,-21.596 -1.344,-3.43 z m -26.4699998,17.82 0.827,25.340003 12.8159998,35.257 -3.928,10.136 -12.6099998,-44.51 z M 31.81879,76.04161 l 0.345,0.826 6.47,15.48 -4.177,38.342 -6.594,-3.526 5.715,-35.7 z m -21.465,-74.697003 0.827,21.373 L 4.1527902,65.02561 0.84679017,30.870607 Z m 2.068,27.323 14.677,32.391 3.307,26.000003 -6.2,36.58 -13.437,-37.241 -0.8269998,-38.342003 z'/>
            </svg>
            <svg preserveAspectRatio='none' overflow='auto' class='part' fill='{data[9]}' data-position='right-leg' id='right-leg' class='right-leg' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='80' height='250.625' viewBox='0 0 80 250.625'>
            <path data-anatomy='right-leg' d='m 26.664979,139.7913 0.663,5.99 -4.647,5.77 -1.55,9.1 -3.1,1.33 -2.655,-13.755 -1.77,-4.88 1.55,-3.107 z m -20.5820002,0.444 3.3200005,9.318 7.0799997,13.755 -1.77,12.647 -5.0899997,-14.2 -4.2000005,-7.987 z m 3.7620005,29.73 1.5499997,4.88 3.32,20.633 0.442,27.51 -4.648,26.847 0.22,-34.39 -4.8670002,-13.754 -0.67,-15.087 z m 10.6229997,12.424 -1.107,41.267 -8.852,33.28 9.627,-4.55 16.046,-57.8 -5.533,-36.384 z m -13.9460002,74.991 c -5.157661,19.45233 -2.5788305,9.72616 0,0 z M 30.177979,4.225305 l 0,22.476 -15.713,31.072 -9.9230002,30.850005 1.033,-21.375005 z m -25.4930002,30.249 -0.118,-0.15 0.793,-2.023 16.5450002,-18.16 1.24,-0.44 -10.98,28.377 z m 6.2550002,10.764 -6.8120002,17.6 -2.274,-21.595 1.344,-3.43 z m 26.47,17.82 -0.827,25.342005 -12.816,35.25599 3.927,10.136 12.61,-44.50999 z m -24.565,12.783005 -0.346,0.825 -6.4700002,15.48 4.1780002,38.34199 6.594,-3.527 -5.715,-35.69999 z m 19.792,51.74999 -5.09,27.29 3.32,-1.776 2.655,8.875 z m 1.671,-126.452995 -0.826,21.375 7.03,42.308 3.306,-34.155 z m -2.066,27.325 -14.677,32.392 -3.308,26.000005 6.2,36.57999 13.436,-37.23999 0.827,-38.340005 z'/>
            </svg>
            <svg preserveAspectRatio='none' overflow='auto' class='part' fill='{data[10]}' data-position='left-hand' id='left-hand' class='left-hand' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='90' height='38.938' viewBox='0 0 90 38.938'>
            <path data-anatomy='left-hand' d='m 21.255,-0.00198191 2.88,6.90000201 8.412,1.335 0.664,12.4579799 -4.427,17.8 -2.878,-0.22 2.8,-11.847 -2.99,-0.084 -4.676,12.6 -3.544,-0.446 4.4,-12.736 -3.072,-0.584 -5.978,13.543 -4.428,-0.445 6.088,-14.1 -2.1,-1.25 L 4.878,34.934 1.114,34.489 12.4,12.9 11.293,11.12 0.665,15.57 0,13.124 8.635,5.3380201 Z' />
            </svg>
            <svg preserveAspectRatio='none' overflow='auto' class='part' fill='{data[11]}' data-position='right-hand' id='right-hand' class='right-hand' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='90' height='38.938' viewBox='0 0 90 38.938'>
            <path data-anatomy='right-hand' d='m 13.793386,-0.00198533 -2.88,6.90000163 -8.4120002,1.335 -0.664,12.4579837 4.427,17.8 2.878,-0.22 -2.8,-11.847 2.99,-0.084 4.6760002,12.6 3.544,-0.446 -4.4,-12.736 3.072,-0.584 5.978,13.543 4.428,-0.445 -6.088,-14.1 2.1,-1.25 7.528,12.012 3.764,-0.445 -11.286,-21.589 1.107,-1.78 10.628,4.45 0.665,-2.447 -8.635,-7.7859837 z'/>
            </svg>
            <svg preserveAspectRatio='none' overflow='auto' class='part' fill='{data[12]}'  data-position='left-foot' id='left-foot' class='left-foot' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='30' height='30' viewBox='0 0 30 30'>
            <path data-anatomy='left-foot' d='m 19.558357,1.92821 c -22.1993328,20.55867 -11.0996668,10.27933 0,0 z m 5.975,5.989 -0.664,18.415 -1.55,6.435 -4.647,0 -1.327,-4.437 -1.55,-0.222 0.332,4.437 -5.864,-1.778 -1.5499998,-0.887 -6.64,-1.442 -0.22,-5.214 6.418,-10.87 4.4259998,-5.548 c 9.991542,-3.26362 9.41586,-8.41457 12.836,1.111 z'/>
            </svg>
            <svg preserveAspectRatio='none' overflow='auto' class='part' fill='{data[13]}' data-position='right-foot' id='right-foot' class='right-foot' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='90' height='38.938' viewBox='0 0 90 38.938'>
            <path data-anatomy='right-foot' d='m 11.723492,2.35897 c -40.202667,20.558 -20.1013335,10.279 0,0 z m -5.9740005,5.989 0.663,18.415 1.546,6.435 4.6480005,0 1.328,-4.437 1.55,-0.222 -0.333,4.437 5.863,-1.778 1.55,-0.887 6.638,-1.442 0.222,-5.214 -6.418,-10.868 -4.426,-5.547 -10.8440005,-4.437 z'/>
            </svg>
</div>
```